# How to Transpose a column Data into separate rows in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I Have a scenario where I have to Convert a Column Data into Separate rows based on a ID values.

For Example

CURRENT DATA :

2100402472 --> Owner;Tenent;Sub-Tenent

EXPECTED DATA :

1. 2100402472  Owner
2. 2100402472  Tenant
3. 2100402472  Sub-Tenant

NOTE : The second Column is as NCLOB.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem of row to columns in Informatica.
You can do this using `Expression` and `Normalizer`.

1. Use Expression to split the datas into multiple columns.

```
id - input/output
in_data - iput only
out_col1= SUBSTRING(
        in_data,
        1,
        CASE
            WHEN INSTR(in_data, ',') > 0 THEN INSTR(in_data, ',') - 1
            ELSE LENGTH(in_data)
        END
    )

out_col2 =  SUBSTRING(
        my_column,
        CASE
            WHEN INSTR(my_column, ',') > 0 THEN INSTR(my_column, ',') + 1
            ELSE LENGTH(my_column) + 1
        END,
        LENGTH(my_column)
    )
```

2. Add a normalizer. In this add ID, and col1, col2 like below diagram. Output will be ID and   category.
   [image: Example] [image: Example2]
3. Add ID and category to the target.